# ErrorException : Illegal string offset

Tags: php, array, laravel, foreach

Eu tenho o seguinte *array*.

```
$polylines = [  
     'latitude' = array(73.9289238, 83.928392832, 03.293892832),
     'longitude' = array(-122.29839238, 21.928918291, 30.203929832)
 ];
```

Estou tentando executar o seguinte `foreach`:

```
 foreach ($polylines as $polyline => $valor){
  $local = $this->getLocal($polyline['latitude'][$valor], $polyline['longitude'][$valor]);

 }
```

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> ErrorException  : Illegal string offset 'latitude'

Me desculpem a ignorância, mas alguém saberia o motivo de tal erro estar ocorrendo? Estou aplicando o `foreach` de forma errada? Desde já grato a todos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, está usando errado. Essa sintaxe faz com que cada elemento de `$polylines` forme um par de variáveis chamadas `$polyline` (o melhor nome seria `$chave` porque é isto que ela é) e `$valor`, já contém a chave, então não pode tentar acessar isso desta forma. Outro erro é que o conteúdo de `$valor` é um *array* e não cada um dos valores dele. Ou seja, esse código todo não faz sentido. Parece que quer pegar os valores em um objeto bidimensional, pelo menos é assim que ele foi montado, então tem que ter dois laços para fazer isto, um para cada dimensão. Algo assim:

```
$polylines = [  
    'latitude' => array(73.9289238, 83.928392832, 03.293892832),
    'longitude' => array(-122.29839238, 21.928918291, 30.203929832)
];
foreach ($polylines as $valor) {
    foreach ($valor as $item) echo $item . "\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TG8G3i). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ForeachBiDimentional). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ForeachBisimenstional.php).

Pra falar a verdade acho que esta estrutura de dados está errada, eu acho que deveria ter um *array* com pares de latitude e longitude. Por isso que sempre falo: o que mais o desenvolvedor precisa dominar é a estrutura de dados, é a modelagem. Quando isso sai errado todo o resto do código fica ruim porque tem que fazer coisas erradas para consertar o erro inicial. Na prática eu acho que vai ter que remontar essa estrutura para ficar usável do jeito que deseja, por isso é muito mais fácil montar certo logo de cara. Algo assim:

```
$polylines = array(['latitude' => 73.9289238, 'longitude' => -122.29839238],
                   ['latitude' => 83.928392832, 'longitude' => 21.928918291],
                   ['latitude' => 03.293892832, 'longitude' => 30.203929832]);
foreach ($polylines as $valor) echo $valor['latitude'] . " <=> " . $valor['longitude'] . "\n";
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qV1zzT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/ForeachBidimentionalDoneRight). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/ForeachBidimentionalDoneRight.php).

Eventualmente nem precisaria dar nomes para a segunda dimensão e usar só a posição, usando só *arrays* normais.